# How to apply IP whitelisting to Openshift routes/services

Tags: routes, openshift, firewall

Say there are two domains, one public, the other restricted to a few selected source IPs:

```
public.example.com   10.0.0.1
private.example.com  10.0.0.2
```

Now, the whitelisting is applied on an external firewall, which then passes the requests on to Openshift router. I have discovered, that it's enough to send the "private" domain name in the "host" header of the public request to actually get the contents from the "private" service:

```
curl https://public.example.com --header "host: private.example.com"
```

got me the contents I was not expecting to see.

What options do I have to actually secure it on the networking level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an annotation to the route to enforce IP whitelisting.

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/ip_whitelist: 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11 192.168.1.12
```

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/architecture/networking/routes.html#whitelist